# jQuery: how to ensure event handlers are attached to all relevant elements in DOM

Tags: jquery

I have around sixty filter buttons in `index.html`, each of which has a `$().click()` event handler attached.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.filter_button_class').click(function(e) {
        console.log("filter button clicked");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

In my CSS file, the `:active` selector ensures a filter button turns blue when it is clicked.

Now the code works fine, most of the time. When `index.html` is first loaded in the browser, the event handlers all seem to attach correctly and the code always works as intended. It's a single page application, so when the user hits the back button to return to `index.html` and clicks again on one of the filter buttons, it indeed turns blue but the code inside of the `.click()` handler sometimes doesn't execute.

I suspect it might be because when `index.html` is reloaded, not all the click handlers get attached before the user clicks a filter button. But when the user clicks the same filter button again (total of twice), the handler usually executes.

**Question** Is there a way to have the code inside of `click()` wait to execute until all event handlers are attached first?

Instead of `.click()` I have also tried `.on()` but this has no effect. It might also be that the issue I'm identifying (event handlers attaching to elements too slowly) is wrong, but I would of course appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Of course, if you're adding them dynamically, not defining them in the HTML, that would be different. Specifically, it [would be this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for your feedback. If by "adding them dynamically" you mean the elements themselves, no the HTML filter buttons are all static. Are you saying the `ready` callback generally ensures that all event handlers will be attached to their elements?

Comment: All that `ready` guarantees is that the callback you give it will be called when the DOM is fully parsed. I think I know what's happening in your scenario; see my updated answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only explanation I can see for the described behavior is that the HTML is so big that it takes a while for the browser to finish parsing it and creating the DOM. While it's doing that, it will partially render the page. By using `ready`, you're telling jQuery you don't want the code in your callback to be called until that process is complete. That leaves a (small) window of opportunity for a user to see a button and click it before the click handler is attached (because the DOM parsing is still happening, and so the `ready` callback hasn't been fired yet). This fits the described symptoms, in particular that the first click doesn't work (`ready` hasn't fired yet) but a subsequent one does (`ready` fired in the meantime).

***If*** that's what's happening, you can avoid it by using event delegation and *not* waiting for the `ready` callback:

```
$(document).on("click", ".filter_button_class", function() {
    // ...handle the click...
});
```

That hooks a click handler on `document` that will only get fired if the click passed through a `.filter_button_class` element. If it did, your handler is called *as though* you had hooked the event on that element instead.

This involves breaking one of the rules of scripts, which is to put them at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag. Instead, specifically because we're dealing with a problem caused by the size of the HTML and the DOM build time, we'd break that rule and put the `script` tags above the problematic content:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="yourcode.js"></script>
<!-- problematic (large) content -->
```

Again, normally we wouldn't do that because it makes the DOM parser wait for the scripts to be fetched, but in this case, as a response to a known issue, it's fine. (Just ensure caching is enabled and working.)

You can see the effect by comparing [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g453pco/) (using `ready`) with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4g453pco/1/) (using a delegated up-front handler and then also a direct handler added via `ready`). With the first, if you're quick, you can click a button and have it not show anything. With the second, if you're quick, you can click a button and only get the "delegated:" message, but later if you click you'll get a "direct:" message and then a "delegate:" one.

Comment: I think your suggestions are spot on as I see no evidence to the contrary. I'm still working through your solution but wanted to ask about what you mean by caching. Do you mean simply placing the JavaScript in separate files - to load once and then they're still in memory, or do you have in mind something else? Thanks!

Comment: @orlando21: I mean ensure that (for instance) you're loading jQuery from a source that sets far-future cache headers so that the browser can keep it in cache. (Same with your own script as well, if it's in a separate file.)